# How to remove anchor tags from soup Python

Tags: python

I am using Beautiful Soup for reading HTML data. After reading it I want to remove some anchor tags. Here is my code:

```
import urllib
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url=raw_input("enter url:")
html=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)

tags=soup('a')
```

Output of tags is in the form:

```
 [<a href="https://www.naukri.com/psu-government-jobs" target="_blank"          
  title="Govt. Jobs">Govt. Jobs</a>,
 <a href="https://www.naukri.com/international-jobs" target="_blank"      
  title="International Jobs">International Jobs</a>,
 <a href="https://www.naukri.com/top-company-jobs" target="_blank" 
 title="Jobs by Company">Jobs by Company</a>,
 <a href="https://www.naukri.com/jobs-by-category" target="_blank" 
  title="Jobs by Category">Jobs by Category</a>,
 <a href="https://www.naukri.com/top-jobs-by-designations" target="_blank"
 title="Jobs by Designation">Jobs by Designation</a>,
  <a target="_blank">Information</a>,
 <a href="https://www.naukri.com/jobs-by-location" target="_blank"         
  title="Jobs by Location">Jobs by Location</a>,
 <a href="https://www.naukri.com/top-skill-jobs" target="_blank" 
 title="Jobs by Skill">Jobs by Skill</a>]
```

I want to drop all the anchor tags which occurs after the tag

```
" <a target="_blank">Information</a>"
```

How I can do this??

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking - the tag you are suggesting does not appear in the code you provided, try to make a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you're having.

Comment: The output is not formatted, each element in the tags list is str?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that each element in tags list is type of str, you could do:

append each element to the new list, when you have the requested string in some element insert him and break the loop.

```
new_li = []
for tag in tags:
  if "Information</a>" in tag:
    new_li.append(tag)
    break
  else:
    new_li.append(tag)

print (new_li)
```

You don't have to create new list, you can modify the same array by doing:

```
for index in range(len(tags)):
  if "Information</a>" in tags[index]:
    index += 1
    break

tags = tags [:index]
print (tags)
```

Iterating each element in the list, break the loop when meeting the requested string, and than override your list with the same list limited to the relevant index.

Comment: omri_saadon: why you are not using tag.text == 'Information'.?

Comment: @VidyaSagar I wasn't sure whether the whole element is str or not.. By assuming that it's str  and by the given info the OP gives, that's what i wrote. It can be tested with tag.text as you said.